# How to use Java Hibernate to add extra information to a joined table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my Java school project I have buildings that contains rooms. Each building can have identical rooms (in structure/material) but with different size. Each room is stored in its own table with specific settings, excluding size.

Currently the Hibernate generates a table "buildings_rooms", to tell which rooms a building contains. The data looks like:

```
building_id   room_id
1             4
1             5
2             4
2             5
```

The problem: How can I add a new column "size" in there, so I can separately define each room to have different size for different buildings rooms?

It should then look something like:

```
building_id   room_id   size
1             4         15
1             5         15
2             4         20
2             5         20
```

In the example above, one building contains 2 rooms that are same size, but the second building contains exactly same rooms but which are larger in size.

Then later when I want to retrieve the total size of the building, I could simply get the sum of the rooms sizes from that table.

(Excuse me for the terms such as "joined table", I am not sure what are the correct terms here since my knowledge on databases are limited.)

The essential parts of my Java code:

Building:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BUILDING")
public class Building {
    private int building_id;
    private String building_name;
    private Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<Room>();

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="buildings_rooms",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="building_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="room_id")}
    )
    public Set<Room> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    ...

    public void addRoom(Room room){
        rooms.add(room);
        room.getBuildings().add(this);
    }
}
```

Room:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROOM")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Room {
    private int room_id;
    private String room_name;
    //private double room_size; // how to handle this? cannot store it in the Room table!
    private Set<Building> buildings = new HashSet<Building>();

    public Room(String room_name, double room_size) {
        this.room_name = room_name;
        //this.room_size = room_size; // how to handle this? cannot store it in the Room table!
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="rooms")
    public Set<Building> getBuildings() {
        return buildings;
    }

    ...
}
```

Example program to create a building with specific sizes for each room:

```
...

    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    Building b1 = new Building("Building1");
    Room b1r1 = new Room("Kitchen",    15.0); // 15 squaremeters in size for this building's room.
    Room b1r2 = new Room("Vestibule",  15.0);
    b1.addRoom(b1r1);
    b1.addRoom(b1r2);
    session.saveOrUpdate(b1);

    Building b2 = new Building("Building2");
    Room b2r1 = new Room("Kitchen",    20.0); // 20 squaremeters in size for this building's room.
    Room b2r2 = new Room("Vestibule",  20.0);
    b2.addRoom(b2r1);
    b2.addRoom(b2r2);
    session.saveOrUpdate(b2);

    transaction.commit();

...
```

But of course this will not work properly yet, since the size is not stored anywhere yet.

Comment: I'm confused by your database schema.  How can a single room be in more than one building?

Comment: @IanMcLaird, It's more like a room type, which specifies the materials etc. but not size.

Comment: But then the building should refer to the room itself (which has a type and a size), rather than the room type.  I'd suggest that the root cause of your problem is that your database isn't normalized sufficiently.

Comment: Which is basically what JB Nizet's answer says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the join table is not a join table anymore, but contains additional, functional information, you just need to map it as an entity:

- Building has a OneToMany with Room
- Room has a size, and a ManyToOne with Building, and a ManyToOne with RoomSettings
- RoomSettings contains settings that are shared by several rooms